# JavaScript array shift

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array like this:

```
var myArray = [{obj1}, {obj2}..];
```

I just want to shift all its items of one step down. So I want my array to become

```
var myArray = [{}, {obj1}, {obj2}..];
```

As you can see, I want an empty object first, and then my other objects.

I already tried to perform a myArray.unshift({ }) function, it works but then Firebug fires me an error while manipulating my array. (Please note that my array is an ExtJS collection).

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it's an ExtJS collection, does not ExtJS have a method to manipulate it? Also, you should show the way you used `unshift` and what caused the problem exactly - and what is the error message.

Comment: Show the actual code you're using that causes the error. Not pieces

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: What is the error firebug displays?

Comment: manipulating the array *how*?

Comment: TypeError: item.addCls is not a function . I'm manipulating portlets in the context of ExtJS Portal. I want to avoid portlets overlap on the resize event. So, when I resize one of the portlets, I check if it overlaps an other portlet of the same line. If yes, I want to down this portlet (the one which is overlapped) in its column (the array). It's very tricky to explain

Answer (score 6):

using the `insert` method (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.Array)

```
var myArray = [{obj1}, {obj2}..];

Ext.Array.insert(myArray, 0, {});
```